# How to check if table is empty , Execute and FetchRow methods in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$RSGetID = $this->MyDBObject->Prepare("SELECT FinalID FROM clothes 
WHERE ClothID=:|1 AND PriceID = :|2 LIMIT 1");

$RSGetID->Execute(2, 199);

$ClothIDRow = $RSGetID->FetchRow();  

return $ClothIDRow->FinalID;
```

This last line gives an error, because there are no rows in the table, so it says:

> "the query did not return any records"

How do I put a condition, that if the table is empty then return 0 , else return the fetched **FinalID** from the database table?

Comment: You are fetching it as array and trying access it as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using some custom DB layer (MyDBObject?) rather than straight-up PDO - it's impossible for us to know how this behaves. There's probably a method along the lines of ->RowCount() or ->NumRows() you can call to see if you got anything back after the ->Execute() - but this is just guessing, since I can't see the DB object you're using.

Comment: // GET THE DATABASE CONNECTION //

  $this->MyDBObject = new UmonMySqlDB

Comment: Google's never heard of "UmonMySqlDB". I'm not sure what you're expecting us to do with this.

Comment: So you're asking us to help you use this custom API that none of us have seen and you won't show us? I mentioned some possible things to try above to see if you got any rows back or not, did you try those?